# How do I omit certain data in a row without removing it all?

Tags: domo

[Domo zero example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjoQ1.png)

I imported data from SQL into Domo. I am building a card and want to remove select 0 values without removing the entire row. Is this possible? The data type has to remain as integer because of the financial formatting.

Comment: I think a screenshot or example data export might help, I'm not sure what exactly you mean by select 0 values.

Comment: I added a screenshot

Comment: So are you saying that instead of showing 0.00 in those 7 spots you'd want it to just show as blank with no data?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in Domo using a Dataflow, in this case I used a MySQL dataflow.

1: Create new MySQL dataflow using this dataset as the input

2: Your transform would like this, where any column you want to remove 0's from would use that NULLIF function https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgoMb.jpg

```
SELECT
`ProjectedExpenses`
,NULLIF(`Amount1`,0) as 'Amount1'
,NULLIF(`Amount2`,0) as 'Amount2'
,NULLIF(`Amount3`,0) as 'Amount3'
FROM `dojohelp99`
```

3: The output dataset of this dataflow is just a select all from this transform table so that would be something like

```
SELECT * FROM transform_data_1
```

Final Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmOBo.jpg